# how to import private frameworks in xcode

Tags: iphone, frameworks, sdk

I am a novice iPhone programmer
I want to use some of the functions in the private framework

https://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks

how should I install them? I tried some ways but it seems that I am doing something wrong.
what I want to use is SpringBoard.framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Try This](http://books.google.com/books?id=i-gABmh50v8C&pg=PA341&lpg=PA341&dq=how+to+import+private+frameworks+in+xcode&source=bl&ots=WtkSfwU8uP&sig=vBYhYj2qkmYHX_RCI8DziNDc3A4&hl=en&ei=LMjjTPKjOJG8vQPnhcnQDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=9&sqi=2&ved=0CFcQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=how%20to%20import%20private%20frameworks%20in%20xcode&f=false)

or

You can easily "add" a private framework in XCode: right click in the left panel, select 
Add > Existing Framework > Add Other, and browse to /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/...>