# In Xcode: What actions is needed to add a framework from System/Library/PrivateFrameworks?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, frameworks, xcode4.5

I need to import a `.framework` found in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/` into my iOS app. How do I make it so? I have the latest Xcode 4.6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to import private frameworks in xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201525/how-to-import-private-frameworks-in-xcode)

Answer (score 3):

In XCode 4.6,

Select Project on the left-pane (in Project Navigator) and select TARGETS and click "Build Phases" tab. Add it under "Link Binary With Libraries".

If XCode couldn't find the path of the framework, then...
Click "Build Settings" Tab (near to "Build Phases") and under 'Search Paths' set your framework path in 'Framework Search Paths'.